# Breaking Change about absolute URL in Social Plugin

Tags: url, facebook-like, alert, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I got this alert from facebook:

...  is currently using the following deprecated features:
Social Plugins (Like Button, Like Box) without absolute URL's in their `href` parameter.

The fb like and fb comment box is used on a Sharepoint site, and the URL in the href parameter is absolute.

Anyone have ideas why facebook is complaining about the code? or have a safe approach I can use to test if the code will work after the change without downtime on the plugins.

Comment: If everything is correct then just enable the migration. The alert is not an error but kind or wrong phrased alert to make you enable the migration or fix things if you might have any issue.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270043/alert-says-using-deprecated-href-without-absolute-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Anvesh says, I checked that my URLs was absolute, enabled the migration, waited a few minutes and tested and nothing breaked.

They should rephrase the message.